# How can I serialize and deserialize a user with local login and with facebook login at the same time with node.js and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I've tried to add a plus parameter to serializeUser method such as email or facebook_id parameter and then I checked that:

```
if (user.id) {
    done(null, user.id);
} else {
    done(null, user.email);
}
```

but it didn't work.

Here is my passport.js file:

```
module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", [id], (err, rows) => {
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });

    passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'login-username',
            passwordField: 'login-password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
            function (req, username, password, done) {
                conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?", [username], (err, rows) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    if (!rows.length) {
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No User found!'));
                    }

                    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong Password!'));

                    return done(null, rows[0]);
                })
            }
        )
    );

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL
    },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function () {
                conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE facebook_id = ?", [profile.id], (err, user) => {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    if (user)
                        return done(null, user);
                    else {
                        let newUser = {
                            facebook_id: profile.id,
                            token: accessToken,
                            email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            name: profle.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName
                        };

                        conn.query("INSERT INTO USER (facebook_id, token, email, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                            [profile.id, profile.accessToken, profile.emails[0].value, profle.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName], (err, rows) => {
                                if (err)
                                    console.log(err)
                                return done(null, newUser);
                            })
                    }
                });
            });
        }))
};
```

If I want to login with local account with username it works, but when I want to login with facebook I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to serialize user into session
```

Is there any way to serialize a facebook user and a local user at the same time?